# Mocking a static class method that is inside a non static class

Tags: mocking, powermock, easymock

If I have

```java
public class ServiceParameters {

    private String ABC;

    public ServiceParameters(ServiceParametersBuilder builder) {
        this.ABC = builder.ABC;
    }

    public static class ServiceParametersBuilder {
        private String ABC;

        public ServiceParameters build() {
            return new ServiceParameters(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and the code that gets invoked elsewhere

```java
serviceParameters = new ServiceParameters.ServiceParametersBuilder().build();
```

How do I mock so that the above code returns me a mocked `ServiceParameters` using EasyMock and PowerMock?

Answer (score 0):

You do not explain, what should be your test. Anyway, there is no any need to mock the ServiceParameters: it does nothing, that should be substituted (or mocked in terms of unit test). You can just create it and go on with your test. 
If ServiceParameters would have a method:

```
public int someMethod()...
```

which reads a file or queries from DB or calls to the third party service etc. it could be mocked for tests like this:

```
public class TestServiceParameters {
    @Mock
    ServiceParameters parametersMock;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.when(parametersMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(1);
        //.... test stuff here
    }
}
```

I have some more examples [here](http://www.codepreference.com/search/label/powermock) .